# google spreadsheet scripts auto fill last cell on new row

Tags: excel

Using a form and google sheet for budget keeping.  The form has category, vendor, and amount.  After submit the sheet includes a time stamp column.  I've added an additional column with the formula:

```
=year(A2) & "-" & if(len(month(A2))=1,"0" & month(A2),month(A2))
```

I need this formula to automatically be added to the same column in the new row (cell at last column and last row) each time the form is submitted.

Suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for an OFFSET type of function. You'll need to offset by row and by column.

I'm not going to write everything for you, but here is basic offset syntax

```
 NameOfDIM.Cells(NameOfDIM.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
```

The two number at the end represent (Vertical, Horizontal) offset :) This should get you close to be able to play around with it till you figure it out

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks for the suggestion.  I ended up using a google script.  The script edits the entire column down to the last row.  Now I need to figure out how to create a trigger so that it will update the column when the form is submitted.